# 2d tile map - how to know which units are at a given tile?

Tags: data-structures

I have a game, it's a 2d tile-based map. Looks like a huge chessboard. Players can have units on the tiles. I need an efficient way of figuring out which units are located at a given tile. The reason being that I don't want to slow down my rendering loop when rendering a portion of the map to screen. I don't want to spend too much time finding which units are at which tile.

Right now I'm thinking of a hash map like so:

```
// Java pseudo-code:
Map<Integer, List<Unit>> units = new HashMap<Integer, List<Unit>>();

// place a unit at tile x,y:
int xy = y * mapWidth + x;
List<Unit> matched = units.get(xy);
if (matched == null) {
    matched = new ArrayList<Unit>();
    units.put(xy, matched);
}
matched.add(new Airplane());

// render a portion of the map to screen, say tiles 20,5 to 50,17
for (int y = 5; y < 17 y++) {
    for (int x = 20; x < 50; x++) {
        List<Unit> matched = units.get(y * mapWidth + x);
        if (matched != null && matched.size() > 0) {
            draw(matched.get(0));
        }
    }
 }
```

I can see this becoming a problem if I have huge maps, and players put a unit on every tile in the map (unlikely to happen). In that case I'd have mapWith*mapHeight entries in my hashmap, and each value is an array itself.

That's my naive take on this problem, would appreciate any alternatives to improve lookup speed or the above case where units occupy every tile of the map,

Thanks

Comment: Couldn't you use a matrix of lists?

Comment: I could, but then don't I have to allocate mapWidth*mapHeight elements up-front? (maybe i misunderstand - assuming you mean List<Unit>[] map = new ArrayList<Unit>[mapWidth*mapHeight]?)

Answer (score 0):

This approach I think suffers in updating scenario. If most of your units are going to change their positions it causes updates to underlying list objects within lookups. So you need first lookup list for old position to amend and then lookup for new position and do the same. This eliminates the benefits of hashmap.

I have a feeling that better idea is to look up from unit to tile. If number of units is less then tiles for the most of time (the general situation until you are not developing hurly-burly massacre game) then lookup from unit to current tile window is better.